# if elseif elseif else in netlogo

Tags: if-statement, functional-programming, netlogo

I want to have a if elseif else if else structure in netlogo but it seems that at the moment it is not working.

```
  ifelse random 100 < 68 [ set HBB-Genes "A,A" ];;68%
         [ifelse random 100 < 2  [set HBB-Genes "S,S"] ;;2%
         [ifelse random 100 < 15 [set HBB-Genes "A,A"];;15%
         [set HBB-Genes "A,A"] ;;15%


         ]]
```

I would like to have a 68% chance of occurring the set HBB-Genes with "A,A" and the next one with 2% chance of occurring and so on. If anyone has experience with netlogo and can help it will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "it seems that at the moment it is not working" — did you get an error message? if so, what was it? what do you mean by "it is not working"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only want to pick one random number, not several.  You can use `let` to store the random number so you can refer to it later. So:

```
let chance random 100
ifelse chance < 68
  [ set HBB-Genes "A,A" ]
  [ ifelse chance < 70
      [ set HBB-Genes "S,S" ]
      [ ifelse chance < 85
          ...
```

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in the following way with if statements otherwise the next if statements got the remainder of the chance of occuring.

```
if geneNumber <= 68
       [
         set HBB-Genes "A,A"
         set color blue
       ]

        if (geneNumber > 68) and (geneNumber <= 83) 
       [
         set HBB-Genes "A,S"
          set color green
       ]

       if (geneNumber > 83) and geneNumber <= 98
       [
         set HBB-Genes "S,A"
          set color green
       ]
       if geneNumber > 98
       [
         set HBB-Genes "S,S"
         set color red
       ]
```