# if elseif else implementation in Netlogo environment

Tags: netlogo

I wish - `if elseif else` statement in NetLogo. How can I do so efficiently? I checked NetLogo documentation no command to do so. [Previous similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330124/if-elseif-elseif-else-in-netlogo)  didn't answer it directly but solved in the context.

One simple solution is:

```
    let flag true
    if(condition1)
    [
    ...
    set flag false
    ]
    if(flag and condition2)   ;else if statement
    [
    ...
    set flag false
    ]
    if(flag)  ;else statement
    [

    ...
    ]
```

I am looking for others more efficient ones.

**Edit:**
added flag in the second if condition upon Nicolas's suggestion.

Comment: Your proposed code is not really like an `if`/`elseif`/`else`: what if `condition1` and `condition2` are both `true`? You would need to change your second `if` to `if (flag and condition2)`. But this quickly gets really messy. Until a better solution is available (which may be sooner than you'd think...) I would advise sticking to the pattern described by Seth in http://stackoverflow.com/a/20332555/487946.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how I missed that. I guess the Seth's approach is only solution. But it makes the a bit less readable overall especially when the blocks include more code.

Comment: We're aware there ought to be a better way. See https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/344

Comment: As Nicolas alluded to, a solution is coming. I actually just wrote an extension for this, though am not quite ready to release it. If you want to check it before then, you can find it here: https://github.com/qiemem/ControlFlowExtension Feel free to open any issues there with suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I can wholeheartedly recommend is:

```
ifelse condition1
  [ ... ]
  [ ifelse condition2
      [ ... ]
      [ ifelse condition3
        [ ... ]
        [ ifelse ...
```

But yeah, the indentation and readability aren't great. For thoughts on possible eventual improvements, see https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/344 and https://github.com/qiemem/ControlFlowExtension.

Comment: Thanks! Does this extension work for windows as well? Though it may seem trivial question, can you please elucidate how to use it. I just pasted it in "the extensions folder in the same location as the NetLogo application." And then imported it in the model using extensions[ControlFlowExtension-master]. But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please open a new question.

Comment: And never say "it doesn't work", always say exactly what happens instead,  including the complete and exact text of any error message.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Sorry should have provided more detail. Please check here-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30226511/extension-not-found-error

Answer (score -1):

I find this form the most readable although the stack of "]" at the end is a little off-putting

```
ifelse item cur brain = 0 [sit][
ifelse item cur brain = 1 [eat][
ifelse item cur brain = 2 [steal][
ifelse item cur brain = 3 [birth][
ifelse item cur brain = 4 [hunger][
ifelse item cur brain = 5 [smell][
]]]]]]
```

it has the advantage of being concise and reading like a "C" style **switch** statement