# Extension not found error with control flow extension

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to use  https://github.com/qiemem/ControlFlowExtension as an alternative to if-else. 
I have it to added to the extensions folder(C:\Program Files (x86)\NetLogo 5.1.0\extensions). The extracted zipped folder from github.
In the NetLogo code I use the following,

```
extensions[ControlFlowExtension-master]
```

But it still shows me the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no release for the extension yet. The zip file that you downloaded is just the source code and doesn't contain the compiled JAR files that you need to use the extension with NetLogo.

If you want to try it out, you will have to build it yourself. For that, you will need to install [`sbt`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/). Then, open a command terminal and `cd` to the folder where you unzipped the file you downloaded from GitHub. This folder should be under the NetLogo `extensions` folder and be called `cf` (rename it if it is not the case). Once you are in the `cf` folder, run:

```
sbt package
```

This should build `cf.jar` and allow you to use the extension by putting

```
extensions [ cf ]
```

at the top of the code tab in your NetLogo model.

Be aware, though, that the extension is still very much experimental. There may be bugs. The syntax could still change. This is why Bryan did not put out an official release yet.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Please reply on any update on release date? I just want to sure it is bug-free.

Comment: As of now, there is a v0.1.0 release: https://github.com/qiemem/ControlFlowExtension/releases. It doesn't mean it's bug free, however. If you find a bug, please report it.

Comment: Great! Thanks! Will do surely in case I come across one.